# Prevent styling of DOM elements inserted into a page

Tags: php, jquery, css

I created a browser extension that inserts DOM elements directly into a page, and I'd like to prevent them from being styled by any inherited CSS already in the page. At the moment, I append my a css call to the head to bring in my own styles. So far my plan has been to use obscure class/id names and create very specific rules. In some cases I've had to use !important. I feel like I'm throwing throwing my morals out the door!

Any thoughts on how I could efficiently prevent inherited styling, and yet allow the browser to render my code efficiently?

Any thoughts on how I could use an iframe to do this? I'm running PHP on the back end.

Comment: I didnt want to post it as an answer since it just an idea, but how about inserting the stuff into an iframe?

Comment: You can't prevent styling of just certain elements. The style of the page is the style of the page.

Comment: Um, the style given to some elements is done by inheritance. It isn't something you can prevent. You can only force it not to inherit but then you must have some default styling where it can lean back on .. e.g. the base style of the element `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent the cascading bit of cascading style sheets but you can define all styles so there is nothing left to inherit.

A quick way of doing this is style them how you want then use webkit's developer tools (or firebug) to view the computed styles for the elements.

Then you can just copy all of the computed styles into your stylesheet. Make sure to use unique IDs so they don't overlap with anything on the page and the styles will be very specific. Add `!important` *...cringing as I say this...* to prevent someones weirdly specific stylesheet from overlapping and make sure your stylesheet call is added in at the end of HEAD or insert it in a style block at the end of the body to make sure it can't be overridden.